# Show that topologies are not determined by their convergent sequences

Tags: general-topology

> German: Topologien werden also durch ihre Filterkonvergenz determiniert. Mit Folgen klappt das einfach nicht mehr. Sei $X$ überzählbar. Sowohl in der diskreten Topologie als auch in der kofiniten Topologie auf $X$ konvergieren lediglich die Folgen, die eventuell konstant sind, und sie konvergieren nur gegen die jeweilige Konstante. Trotzdem sind beide Topologien verschieden. 1:0 für die Filter! - [Source](https://matheplanet.com/matheplanet/nuke/html/article.php?sid=936)
>
> Translation by Me: Topologies are hence determined by their filter convergence. With sequences that doesn't happen any more. Let $X$ be an uncountable set. In both the discrete and cofinite topology only the sequences converge which are eventually constant and they converge only to their respective constants. Despite of that, both the topologies are different. 1:0 for the filter.

Has the Author made a mistake here? In this [post](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/79594/which-sequences-converge-in-a-cofinite-topology-and-what-is-their-limit) on MSE, it is said that if sequence is only of different terms then everything is a limit but the other says that in Discrete and Cofinite we have the same convergent sequences.

Comment: It must be a typo. My guess is that the author meant to write co**countable** topology, which has the same convergent sequences as the discrete topology.

Comment: I don't catch at all the meaning, in your last sentence of "1:0 for the Filter."

Comment: Hmm so it's like one positive point for the filter. You know like football they give one scorenpoint for team which makes goal @Jean Marie

Comment: Oh, I see. I should have guessed !

Comment: Thanx @JoséCarlosSantos