# Is the metric topology determined by its convergent sequences?

Tags: sequences-and-series, general-topology, metric-spaces

I am aware that in a first countable space (and thus any metric space) is completely determined by its convergent sequences *and* their limits, *i.e.*,

> If $\tau_1$ and $\tau_2$ are two first countable topologies on a set $X$ such that $x_i\to c$ in $\tau_1$ iff $x_i\to c$ in $\tau_2$, then $\tau_1 = \tau_2$.

However, this raises the following question: If two metrics on a space have the same convergent sequences, will they have the same limits as well (and thus the same topology)?

Comment: maybe more accurate to say "two metrics on a space" rather than "two metric spaces", since problem doesn't make much sense if the underlying set isn't the same.

Comment: @MW agreed and edited.

Comment: https://math.stackexchange.com/q/4554239/688539

Answer (score 16, accepted):

I believe this is true -- we *can* recover what the sequences converge to.

Say $(a_n)$ is a sequence in $X$ that we know converges, but we don't know what it converges *to*. There will be a unique $x \in X$ so that the new sequence $(a_1, x, a_2, x, a_3, x, a_4, x, \ldots)$ is convergent (which we can detect), and this $x$ is necessarily the limit of the sequence $(a_n)$.

Of course, this process is not "computable" in any sense. I have no idea how one would find such an $x$ in practice (though maybe it's doable in case $X$ is compact...) but, in the abstract, this shows that the convergent sequences remember limits.

---

I hope this helps ^_^

Comment: Maybe I am missing something, but is this an answer to OP's question? There are two metric spaces, for which say $a_n\to x_1$ (in $X_1$) and $a_n\to x_2$ (in $X_2$).

Comment: @WishYouTheBest As the answer noted, the $x$ in the answer is unique. That is to say, if $x_1 \neq x_2$, then $(a_1, x_1, a_2, x_1, a_3, \cdots)$ is convergent in $X_1$ but not in $X_2$, so the two spaces do not share convergent sequences in that case.

Comment: @DavidGao Thanks, I couldn't figure out your point!

Answer (score 9):

This is just to expand a bit on HallaSurvivor's answer.

It turns out that limits of convergent sequences can be encoded in sequences themselves: In any $T_1$ space, $a_i\to x$ iff the sequence $a_1, x, a_2, x, a_3, x, a_4, \ldots$ converges. Hence the topology of a first countable $T_1$ space is completely determined by its convergent sequences.

Comment: Worth noting that $T_1$ is absolutely necessary here, since for $X=\{0,1\}$ the distinct topologies $\tau_i=\{\emptyset,\{i\},X\}$, for $i=0,1$, each have the property that every sequence converges (in $\tau_0$ they all converge to $1$, and in $\tau_1$ they all converge to $0$).  As a sillier example, the trivial topology has this property as well.

Comment: @MW I was just going to add that! :)

Comment: Here is an example to see that first countable is also necessary: the weak and norm topology on $\ell^1$ have the same convergent sequences (with the same limits) but are very different topologies

Comment: @AlessandroCodenotti A more accessible example would be cocountable and discrete topologies on an uncountable set. :)